# What is the initial input used in a NOR gate for a reset-set latch?

Tags: relay, logic-gates, feedback

[image: Question]

[image: SR latch diagram]

What happens the moment the reset-set latch is switched on?

Comment: Hmm can you post questions as text rather am image.

Comment: Where is the s/r latch implemented in the relays?

Comment: *In general* in logic the initial state is unknown (due to residual charges lying around the circuit) and that's *the* major need for asynchronous resets. Relay logic of course starts switched off but your circuit is not a latch, it's simply a combinatory gate (a nor, in fact). Usually you implements relay latches with diodes or, better, with multiple contacts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your set-reset latch implemented with your relay NOR gates:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe0PaU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

At power on all relays are released, but the coils of RLY1-B and RLY2-B are powered. Each 'B' relay will then start to operate. If the relays were identical then each one would disconnect the other, then fall back and operate again continuously. However in practice they won't be identical, so one relay will probably break its contact first, causing the other relay to fall back and hold the first relay operated.

If one of the input switches SW1 or SW2 are operated at power on then its 'A' relay will operate, ensuring that its 'B' relay does too because the 'B' relay of the opposite gate will be forced off. If both switches are operated at power on then both 'A' relays will operate, forcing both 'B' relays off.

To ensure that the latch powers up in a known state you could make one relay slower to operate by adding some resistance in series with its coil, or using a different relay which operates slower. In complex relay logic techniques such as late breaking contacts, an auxiliary winding shorted out by a Normally Closed contact, or a copper 'slug' acting as shorted turns were often used to make a relay slower to operate.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.  My English is not so good, but what do you mean by "at power on all relays are released"?

Comment: A relay is called 'operated' when the armature moves towards the pole face and pushes the contacts to their 'operated' state (in this case 'open'). 'Released' is the opposite state where the contacts are not operated. A relay can be powered but still have contacts 'released' if there is insufficient voltage or time for the armature to move enough to 'operate' them.

Comment: To put it simply, when a connection is made between the pole and the 'normally open' contact, it is 'operated.'  At all other times, it is released?

Comment: In this case the relays have normally closed contacts, which are 'operated' when they **don't** make a connection. With changeover contacts there is a position where both NC and NO contacts are open, where you can say the relay is 'half-operated'. Some relays 'make before break' contacts that can be deliberately 'half operated' to connect all the contacts together.

Comment: Would you mind if we continue this conversation in chat?

Comment: No I wouldn't mind.

Comment: Ok, hopefully I can get it working.  I'm in http://chat.stackexchange.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127999/discussion-between-masu-and-bruce-abbott).